# Regex to detect comments/Strings without conflict, Method names, Class names

Tags: java, regex, string, methods, comments

I am creating a simple IDE.

This is done by detecting code types using regex and coloring them in a JTextPane.

Currently, I can detect:

- Comments
- String literals
- Numbers
- Key / Restricted words

Below is a sample of my program:

[image]

**Question 1: My regex detects String literals then comments. Thus,it overwrites it's color causing comments inside Strings to be colored incorrectly.**

This is the regex used to detect comments:

```
Pattern commentsSingle = Pattern.compile("\\/\\/.*");
Pattern commentsMulti = Pattern.compile("\\/\\*.*?\\*\\/", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

This is the regex used to detect String literals:

```
Pattern strings = Pattern.compile("((?<!\\\\)\\\"(.*?)\\\"(?<!\\\\\\\"))");
```

Is there a way that my comments regex will not detect inside String literals (" " double quotes)

or maybe

Strings that will not detect inside comments

**Question 2: I wish to detect method names (user created) and coloring them a different color.**

Is there a regex that can detect method names?

**Question 3: Just like Q2, I wish to detect class names and coloring them a different color.**

Is there a regex that can detect class names?

--

*Sorry about my long post i am relatively new to regex and any help would be appreciated very much.*

Comment: You clearly have not thought your logic through.

Comment: @PM 77-1 Do u mean i should not detect comments, then strings and overwriting its colour? Or my regex logic is not correct?

Comment: **Pro-tip:** Neither the slash (`/`) nor the quotation mark (`"`) has any special meaning in regexes.  The quotation mark needs to be escaped by *one* backslash because it's in a string literal, and the slash doesn't need any.

Answer (score 1):

**Pro tip**: You're doing it wrong.

There are far too many complex structures in programming languages to account for with regex. Even if the language was fairly simple, your regular expressions would quickly become far too unwieldy to maintain and update. Not only this but regular expressions quickly start to run slowly on large datasets.

Your best bet is [Lexing/Parsing](http://parsingintro.sourceforge.net/).

You'll be able to tag sections of the code quite quickly and be able to support a variety of languages as well.

Comment: I understand i should not be using regex to do everything, but this is just my personal simple project and im learning regex.. i just need abit of help in fixing my regex in detecting very simple codes

Comment: @user3188291 the problem is that you want to detect method names and class name which are almost indistinguishable except from their context. Regex and context do *not* play well with each other and you'll have such a difficult time trying to get it to work. To be honest I don't think it's possible.

Additionally, implimenting a lexer is not difficult and takes a small amount of time. A parser takes just a little more work assuming you have a grammar for the language.

Comment: Oh ok.. if qn 2 and qn 3 cannot be solved i understand. thank you for your feedback.. but the main purpose of my small project is to understand and learn how to use regular expressions. i do not wish to use other methods thanks

Answer (score 1):

The iismathwizard is right and a parser would be better, but I think that as a regex exercise, it is quite good idea. However you can try with this:

- method: `[\w$]+(?=\([^)]*\)\s*\{)` [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eL9uO7/2)
- class for Java: `(?<=class\s{0,1000})([\w$]+)(?=(?:\s*(?:implements|extends)\s*(?:[\w$]+))?\s*\{)` modified [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cZ4hN9/2)
- comments, group by type: `^(?:\s*?)(?:[^"\n\r]*?(?:"[^"]+?")?[^"\n\r]*?)?(?:(?<endOfLine>//[^\n]*)|(?<javadoc>/\*\*(?:.|\n)+?(?=\*/)\*/)|(?<block>/\*(?:.|\n)+?(?=\*/)\*/))` with [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wG3qS1/1)

Actually, I would rather split this question into 3 separate question, it is more plausible that someone will spend some time to answer one question, that 3.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.. i will try to split the question into 3 the next time! I have tested both regex in regex101 but it does not work.. But i still appreciate your help. thanks!

Comment: Could you show me how you check on regex101 if regex is valid? It would be easier to find solution. [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cZ4hN9/1) class, [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eL9uO7/1) method